# JS and Bootstrap for responsive menu?

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, responsive

I am building my own project to get experience on Laravel, js/jquery, bootstrap etc..
So this is the structure of the site / layout that i use for all views:

```
| Home  |----- content -----| FRIENDS |
| Blog  |----- content -----|  George |
| Forum |----- content -----|  Pablo  |
| About |----- content -----|  Boris  |
--------------------------------------
| -------------- footer ------------- |
```

So as you can see I have 3 cols. The first with the menu that u can navigate, the second that shows the current laravel view and the third is the logged user friends. Friends are passed to every view with ViewServiceProvider and thats how we get them.

What I want is to have the following structure for mobile:

```
|------header with icons ------|
|---------- content -----------|
|---------- content -----------|
|---------- content -----------|
| ---------- footer ---------- |
```

The header is now horizontal and contains this icons: (home icon) (friends icon) (notifications icon) (chats icon)

And here my questions come because I want to make it right ...

1. How to change the first column with the navigation to become not only horizontal but to change its anchor words with icons ?
   Should I use js and detect when the window is X pixels and then make DOM manipulation and change them + remove/add anothers ?
   Or maybe I should play with boostraps display properties ?
   Or maybe I should add another horizontal navigation to the html that is with display-none and when we get to X pixels, to display that navigation element and to hide the other one ?
2. In that header navigation, I will have "friends" icon and when you click it, it will load all of your friends on the whole screen of the phone. As I said the friends data is passed to every view automatically and I dont have a different view with friends that I can call from clicking the anchor. So what should I do ?
   Create view with the friends data ?
   Or use bootstrap on X pixels to display back "friends" column(because it was hidden when we are on other pages on the mobile), giving it 12 cols and display-none the "content" column?

Comment: use @media in css to change the site aspect in mobile expl `@media (max-width: 1024px) { ... }` here the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

```
*Navbar*

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Forum</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


*Contents*
 
   <div class="row">
         <div class = "col-md-12">
            *Contents goes here*
         </div>
   </div>


*Footer*

<footer>
    <p>Your Footer Content</p
</footer>
```